# Unicode in right pointing bullet

Tags: unicode, openoffice.org

What is the unicode for this right pointing arrows bullet in openoffice?

[image]

Comment: you can try any arrow from this page http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp

Comment: [`U+27A2 THREE-D TOP-LIGHTED RIGHTWARDS ARROWHEAD`](https://codepoints.net/U+27A2)

Comment: thanks Phylogenesis for answering my question. this was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many sites out there where you can search based on name.  [this one](http://unicode-table.com/) for example allows you to input `right arrow`, review the results, and then refine the search until you find:

[Three-D Top-Lighted Rightwards Arrowhead U+27A2 ➢](http://unicode-table.com/en/27A2/)